# Play RTSP stream on iOS with LIVE555

Tags: ios, rtsp, live555

How to modify the example "openRTSP" of [Live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) to display a RTSP stream in a iOS App ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at dropcam https://github.com
Personally I find it harder to use than some other frameworks including the ones we use, but the dropcam example should give yo what you need.

Comment: if your just trying to come up to speed with rtsp on the iphone and live 555 is not a requirement you can also look at http://www.streammore.tv

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MobileVLCKit` which use live555 internally.

You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48340854/2003734

Comment: Thanks to remember me I had this nice project exactly 5 years ago.

Comment: Well, when I was looking for a solution, I found your question unanswered. It's not only for you, it can also help someone else :)